# Cable Ethernet stopped working Xubuntu 19.04

Tags: xubuntu, internet, ethernet, 19.04

Afternoon all.

Yesterday (11th Oct) at midnight, my laptop lost connection to the internet via ethernet cable.  I can still connect via wifi.

I have a second laptop, which dual boots with Xubuntu 19.04 and Windows 10.  This second laptop can still connect to ethernet in both Windows 10 and Xubuntu 19.04, so it is not a modem / router issue.

I had managed to restore the ethernet by deleting the auto eth0 settings, and reconfiguring, but now that too has stopped working (and I cannot restore auto eth0!).

Can anyone help walk me through troubleshooting this issue please?

---

@heynnema:  the information you requested.

```
dkms status
digimend, 8, 5.0.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed
digimend, 8, 5.0.0-31-generic, x86_64: installed
```

```
sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for bac: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 07
       serial: b0:5a:da:c9:aa:2a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 multicast=yes
       resources: irq:18 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b4000000-b4000fff memory:b4800000-b4803fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
       logical name: wlp13s0
       version: 81
       serial: 94:65:9c:b9:9a:ba
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-31-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 ip=192.168.1.114 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:44 memory:b2000000-b2001fff
```

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

```
cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
cat: '/etc/netplan/*.yaml': No such file or directory
```

@heynnema: The second run at sudo lshw -C network:

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 07
       serial: b0:5a:da:c9:aa:2a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 multicast=yes
       resources: irq:18 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b4000000-b4000fff memory:b4800000-b4803fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
       logical name: wlp13s0
       version: 81
       serial: 94:65:9c:b9:9a:ba
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-31-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:44 memory:b2000000-b2001fff
```

@heynnema: Third times the charm!

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 07
       serial: b0:5a:da:c9:aa:2a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 multicast=yes
       resources: irq:18 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b4000000-b4000fff memory:b4800000-b4803fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
       logical name: wlp13s0
       version: 81
       serial: 94:65:9c:b9:9a:ba
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-31-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:43 memory:b2000000-b2001fff
```

But still no auto eth0.  How would I know if I have a cat5 or cat6 cable?

@heynnema: This should hopefully be the last one:

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 07
       serial: b0:5a:da:c9:aa:2a
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.1.195 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b4000000-b4000fff memory:b4800000-b4803fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
       logical name: wlp13s0
       version: 81
       serial: 94:65:9c:b9:9a:ba
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-31-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:43 memory:b2000000-b2001fff
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99871/discussion-on-question-by-bryncoles-cable-ethernet-stopped-working-xubuntu-19-04).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

After lengthy troubleshooting using the `sudo lshw -C network` command, it looked like no cable was connected to the computer, or the cable was defective (user was not using a cat 5e or cat 6 cable), or the switch/hub/router/modem wasn't connected.

It was determined that the computer really saw a enp7s0 ethernet device, not a eth0 device. By creating a new fresh NetworkManager GUI connection script using enp7s0, and testing with kernels -29, -30, and -31, it all seems to work again. Old connection scripts using eth0 were deleted.

If it fails again, you'll need to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and retest the ethernet network interface.